# Java sort (TimSort-MergeSort) in java 7 : Dangerous

Tags: java, exception, sorting, comparator

I am having trouble to sort my collection by Collections.sort() using my own Comparator implementation. 
The exception thrown is-->"IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract! 
In my OrdersBean I have over-ridden the hashCode as this:

```
@Override    
    public int hashCode() {
    return this.getServiceOrderName().toUpperCase().hashCode();
}
```

I have not over-ridden equals() and using that of the Object class only(should not be a problem I feel).

And I have implemented the comparator as this:

```
public static final Comparator<OrdersBean> ordersComparator=new Comparator<OrdersBean>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(OrdersBean first, OrdersBean second)
    {
        if(Double.parseDouble(first.getPriority())<Double.parseDouble(second.getPriority()))
            return -1;
        else
            if(Double.parseDouble(first.getPriority())>Double.parseDouble(second.getPriority()))
                return +1;
            else
            {
                if((first.getPlatformType().equalsIgnoreCase("EV-DO Carrier ADD")) &&
                        (second.getPlatformType().equalsIgnoreCase("EV-DO Carrier ADD")))
                            return -1;

                if((first.getPlatformType().equalsIgnoreCase("T1 Augment")) &&
                        (second.getPlatformType().equalsIgnoreCase("T1 Augment")))
                            return -1;

                if(first.getPlatformType().equalsIgnoreCase("EV-DO Carrier ADD"))
                    return -1;
                else
                    if(second.getPlatformType().equalsIgnoreCase("EV-DO Carrier ADD"))
                        return +1;
                    else
                        if(first.getPlatformType().equalsIgnoreCase("T1 Augment"))
                            return -1;
                        else
                            if(second.getPlatformType().equalsIgnoreCase("T1 Augment"))
                                return +1;
                            else
                                return -1;
            }

    }
};
```

Please suggest me , where I am going wrong???

I have changed the code now as follows, Its running fine for sort() method but it is now eventually causing an error in a later code where this comparator is passed to the Tree-Set, where duplicates are not allowed, and thus all the cases of similar platform types where the comparator return 0 , those orders are not added to this sortedSet;(as duplicates are not allowed):

```
public static final Comparator<OrdersBean> ordersComparator=new Comparator<OrdersBean>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(OrdersBean first, OrdersBean second)
    {
        int diffProrties=(int)(Double.parseDouble(first.getPriority())-Double.parseDouble(second.getPriority()));
        if(diffProrties != 0)
            return diffProrties;

        if(first.getPlatformType().equalsIgnoreCase(second.getPlatformType()))
            return 0;

        if(first.getPlatformType().equalsIgnoreCase("EV-DO Carrier ADD"))
            return -1;
        if(second.getPlatformType().equalsIgnoreCase("EV-DO Carrier ADD"))
            return +1;
        if(first.getPlatformType().equalsIgnoreCase("T1 Augment"))
            return -1;
        if(second.getPlatformType().equalsIgnoreCase("T1 Augment"))
            return +1;

        return 0;


    }
};
```

Comment: You never return 0? What happens when you compare an object with itself?

Comment: Does it have anything to do with needing some branch to return 0? (Beat me to it, SJuan76!)

Comment: it also seems like some of your platformtype checks are redundant.  do you need to expliclty compare only 2 possible values?  why not directly compare `first.getplatformType` to `second.getplatformtype` ?

Comment: No it does not need to be compared with itself, The collection will always have unique objects( as initially I have used a Set(LinkedHashSet) to collect all the objects and later assigned it to the list(ArrayList) constructor.So it only has unique objects, It should never return) zero.

Comment: as The docs suggest---It is generally the case, but not strictly required that (compare(x, y)==0) == (x.equals(y)); Mine is a somewhat similar scenario;

Comment: @BlackVegetable; yeah!! why should I return zero If I don't need it,LOL

Comment: You should return zero to make your comparator not violate its contract, that's why. If you fail to return zero for `first == second`, you have violated the contract. Note that I'm not talking about `equals`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`compare(a,b)` must be the same as `-compare(b, a)` otherwise there is no deterministic way to compare a and b.  You have

```
if((first.getPlatformType().equalsIgnoreCase("EV-DO Carrier ADD")) &&
   (second.getPlatformType().equalsIgnoreCase("EV-DO Carrier ADD")))
       return -1;
```

This says a < b AND b < a which makes no sense.

Comment: I agree with you, But i earlier treated this as an equal case when both the platform types were equal,I was returning 0, But then it broke my code at a later stage in the application where this same comparator is used to create a treeSet, and in that case when it gets 0 from compare() it doesn't adds the objects to the set, as the objects would then be equal, so I'll loose all those  objects which have similiar platform types,, This comparator is to be used at both places effectively,,

Comment: You have to compare on a field which is different rather than return 0. Tree collections don't allow duplicate keys, so if you want "duplicate" you have to make them different some how.

Comment: You have to compare on a field which is different rather than return 0. Sets don't allow duplicates. If you want duplicates you can use a List or add a field to make the keys different.

Answer (score 3):

Comparator must follow a [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare%28T,%20T%29), in particular, if `compare(A, B) < 0`, then it has to be that `compare(B, A) > 0`. You comparator will violate this if you pass it two objects with platform "EV-DO Carrier ADD".